# Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) всегда возвращает false

Tags: unity3d

Доброй ночи!
Не так давно обновился unity 2020 с версии 1.0f1 на версию 1.3f1. И после обновления(я проверял) появилась проблема с Input. Метод Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) почему-то перестал реагировать на нажатия клавиши пробел и стал возвращать false в результате. Я до ифа сейчас специально написал проверки:
Debug.Log(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"));
Debug.Log(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));
Самое интересное, что к примеру left ctrl работает(Fire1), также работают всякие там Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") и т.п Проблема касается только пробела.
Я помню, что уже сталкивался с подобным поведением в свежих версиях 2019 lts, но потом я ушел на 2020, где до недавних пор все было хорошо. Но затем выкатили обнову с черной темой для всех и опять появилась эта проблема. Представлю ниже код и скриншоты окна Input Manager.

```
    private void Update()
{
    ReadInput();
    CheckGround();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
    Jump();
}

private void ReadInput()
{
    _horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    //animator.SetFloat("Walk", Mathf.Abs(_horizontal));
    
    if (_isClimb)
        return;

    Debug.Log(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"));
    Debug.Log(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _isGrounded)
    {
        _isCanJump = true;
    }

    ...

}
```

[image: Input Manager]

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что проблема связана с линуксом.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/keycode-space-or-jump-is-not-working-on-ubuntu.952556/

Надо ждать фикса.